# How to escape "<"?

Tags: mysql, string, powershell, escaping

How do you escape this command in PowerShell?

```
mysql -uuser -ppass -hlocalhost -Ddb < .\someSqlFile.sql
```

I need to escape the `<`.

Contents of `someSqlFile.sql`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM some_table 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/output.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: you can import something into the DB `<` and export something from the DB `>`

Comment: @juergend I don't think you understand. It takes `<` literally in powershell and this does not happen in CMD

Comment: I can't test it - but have you tried a backtick    `

Comment: @Itchydon Like this `<   ?

Comment: yes - just like that?

Comment: @Itchydon ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database '<

Comment: Sorry! Never mind, backticks are commonly used to escape in PoSh - someone else will know in your case

Comment: @Itchydon Don't be sorry! I got closer with your suggestion

Comment: Are you sure the redirect is not pointing the wrong way round?

Comment: @Itchydon Yeah because I'm trying to execute a query. I will add the contents of the sql file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't support input redirection (`<`). Either execute the command with CMD (from PowerShell):

```
cmd /c mysql -uuser -ppass -hlocalhost -Ddb '<' .\someSqlFile.sql
```

or pipe the content of the file into the command:

```
Get-Content .\someSqlFile.sql | & mysql -uuser -ppass -hlocalhost -Ddb
```

Comment: I have a question: instead of having the command in a MySql file can I just pipe it as a here-string?

Comment: Also, what does the `&` do after the `|`?

Comment: Yes, piping a here-string or an array of strings should work as well. The `&` is PowerShell's [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators). It's not required when your command is a bare word like in this case, but you must use it when your command is a string (e.g. because it contains spaces). `"C:\path to\mysql.exe"` would just echo the string, whereas `& "C:\path to\mysql.exe"` would run the executable.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using input redirection is to use the `source` command in the mysql client.

```
mysql -uuser -ppass -hlocalhost -Ddb -e "source ./someSqlFile.sql"
```

I am not a PS user, so I can't offer the right syntax for the last argument. It's supposed to be one argument, but it contains a space. I searched a few other sites looking for a concise technique to use a single argument including spaces in PS, but it's not that easy I guess. :-)

To solve your problem of exporting one table in CSV format another way, you might like to use mysqldump:

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppass -hlocalhost --tab=C:/tmp db some_table
```

This outputs a file `some_table.sql` and a file `some_table.txt` which are the DDL and the data for that table, respectively.